# User input failing if statement and I don't know why

Tags: java, algorithm, loops

My program is calculating and then printing the users BMR value, based on their age, height, weight, and gender.

However, my program is not working when it comes to checking the gender based on the input, and jumping straight to the else statement.
This is my code so far, how do I fix it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MaintainingWeight
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //Instance Variables
        int age, weight, inches; //weight in pounds, height inches
        double BMR;
        String gender;

        //Program Introduction Welcoming the user
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hello fellow user, this program will help determine \nyour BMR value and tell the amount of chocalate bars you will need");
        System.out.println("in order to maintain your body weight.");

        //Ask the User to input their age, weight and height
        System.out.println("Please enter your age.");
        age = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Next enter your weight in pounds");
        weight = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Now enter your height by inches\n (Reminder: to find your height in inches mutiply your height by feet to 12.000. (feet * 12.000))");
        inches = keyboard.nextInt();

        //Tell the user their gender then print their BMR Value
        System.out.println("Please enter your gender. Enter M as Men or W as women");
        gender = keyboard.nextLine();

        if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("M"))
        {
            System.out.println("Your BMR value is: ");
        }
        else if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("W"))
        {
            System.out.println("Your BMR Value is: ");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    //Print to the user the amount of chocolate bars they need to consume to maintain their weight

}
```

Comment: That looks fine to me. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @user3189142 I think he need the equation

Comment: Well he's going to run into some problems because BMR is calculated with the metric system

Comment: @user3189142 maybe not , though. There are also some calculator that use US unit.

Comment: @PoomrokcThe3years these calculators first convert to metric before doing the calculation. user3189142 was probably referring to that.

Comment: When i run it it won't let me enter M or W is their sonething wrong with the keyboard object

Comment: When i run the program its tells tell user if the. Are a man or women but the program does not let me input the keyboard and is not outputing the BMR value

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I've never actually used java, so forgive me if I make any coding errors...

```
if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("M"))
{
    System.out.print("Your BMR value is: "); //Prints without a newline I assume
    System.out.print((66 + (13.8 * (weight * 0.454)) + (5 * (height * 2.54)) - (6.8 * age));
}
else if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("W"))
{
    System.out.print("Your BMR value is: "); //Prints without a newline I assume
    System.out.print((655 + (9.6 * (weight * 0.454)) + (1.8 * (height * 2.54)) - (4.7 * age));
}
else
{
    System.out.println();
}
```

Alright, the problem is that keyboard.nextLine() is adding a \n to the end. Two ways to fix:

```
if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("M\n"))
{
}
else if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("W\n"))
{
}
```

OR

```
if (gender.contains("m") || gender.contains("M"))
{
}
else if (gender.contains("w") || gender.contains("W"))
{
}
```

Comment: I add the bmr equation in the loop but when i run it it does not output the BMR when i enter M or W .what am i doing wrong